# Can I send a KILL signal to the current process in a terminal emulator with a keybinding?

Tags: bash, process, zsh, kill

<strike>Bash</strike> Terminal emulators can send `SIGINT` and <strike>`SIGSTOP`</strike> `SIGTSTP` to processes via `C-c` and `C-z` respectively. [(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stty.1.html) [(2)](https://pastebin.com/raw/Tx0X8xTx)

I have a process that is ignoring both these signals (`tmux wait-for hello`)? Is there an easy way to kill this process without looking up its PID and sending it a signal  via a keybinding (for example by sending `SIGKILL`)?

Comment: Reword in response to ["downvote: no comment"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes)

Answer (score 3):

That assumption is not correct. These key combinations are interpreted by the terminal (emulator) and not by the shell. The shell does not see them.

You can stop the foreground process with `^Z` and execute `kill -KILL %%` then. You can probably do the second part via key binding.

Comment: **That assumption is not correct** Interesting...

Comment: @AttRigh `^Z` sends `SIGSTOP` which cannot be ignored.

Comment: Hmmm... and yet it doesn't work :/. The [man pages](https://linux.die.net/man/2/signal) do agree with you though: **"The signals SIGKILL and SIGSTOP cannot be caught or ignored."**

Comment: Hmm, so I think that `^Z` sends `SIGTSTP`, at least on my machine. `stty --all` includes a list of "keybindings" and `^Z` looks like it is bound to "susp". This is consistent with the fact that `kill -TSTP` does not stop `tmux wait-for`, but `kill -STOP does`

Comment: Yep, so I'm pretty sure from [stty's manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stty) that i) the terminal cannot send a `STOP` signal only a "terminal stop signal" (`TSTP`), ii) it cannot send a kill signal, iii) it can send a QUIT signal (`C-\` on my machine). In my case (`tmux wait-for`) a quit signal is "strong enough" to kill the process.

Comment: I guess that the terminal does not send any signals to `tmux` because a virtual terminal has to put its terminal in raw mode in order to get all the keys. Otherwise the special keys would not work for the processes running within `tmux`. Sorry, that does not make wrong what I said before but I should have realized the special case for `tmux` earlier.

Comment: **Sorry, that does not make wrong** Everything was correct apart from it seems like the terminal sends `SIGTSTP` (citation: **susp CHAR CHAR will send a terminal stop signal** ( [stty man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stty.1.html))). This signal can be ignored by a process unlike `SIGSTOP` ([terminal output showing this](https://pastebin.com/raw/JMNFvfJU))
.

Comment: Proof that `^Z` sends `SIGSTP` on my machine: https://pastebin.com/raw/3JeTXhFp

Comment: I deleted the comment above that contained the following LIE: **"processes may ignore both SIGTERM [ I meant SIGSTOP] and SIGINT"**. Processes may ignore *both SIGINT (`^C`) and SIGTSTP (`^Z`)`* (Sorry I would have preferred to edit the comment :/ I just wanted to mark the lie as wrong)

Answer (score 1):

It's not the terminal emulators that send SIGINT/SIGQUIT/SIGTSTP, it's the terminal or pseudo-terminal device driver in the kernel that does.

Assuming it's configured with `stty intr '^C'` for instance, when a `^C` character (`0x3` byte) is received from the terminal over a serial connection or from a terminal emulator from the master side of the pseudo-terminal, the kernel sends the SIGINT signal to all the processes in the *foreground process group* of the tty device (and it's your interactive shell that decides which is the foreground process group at any given time).

On Linux at least there's no equivalent terminal driver (termios) setting for mapping a character to a SIGKILL signal sent to the foreground process group.

The `xterm` terminal emulator can be configured to send some signals including SIGKILL with the `send-signal(kill)` action upon some X11 event (such as KeyPress events)

```
xterm -xrm 'XTerm.VT100.translations: #override Ctrl <Key>k: send-signal(kill)'
```

For instance would start an `xterm` that sends SIGKILL upon <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>.

In the default menu that you get with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + MouseButton1, you can do the same with the `Send KILL Signal` entry.

However, it sends it to the process group that it created itself typically to run your shell, not the foreground process group of the slave terminal device. So it will likely not do what you want.

Even if you found a way for the terminal emulator to send SIGKILL to the foreground process group, first it would not be able to do it if the processes were running as a different uid, but also it would not do what you want if  for instance you started a `ssh` / `script` / `screen`... session in it, as it would then need to send the signal to  the foreground process group of *their* tty device.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using a GUI terminal emulator, chances are it can send SIGKILL, just look through its menus. I use Konsole and in the Edit menu, there is a "Send signal" submenu, where I can send a SIGKILL among many others.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't answer the key question, which is how _"to kill this process without looking up its PID"_.